# How to sort data from database in array by attributes using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Help sir. Im still new to Yii Framework.
I've been wanting to fetch data and sort it by category using Yii Framework.

This is my table **esolat_infografik** and i want to fetch data by category from column **infografik_category**

[image]

And i want to put all data by category here in tab
[image]

This is my code

```
public function infoKiblat()
{
    $ref = EsolatInfografik::findByAttributes(array('infografik_category'=>'Info Kiblat'));
    $html = "";

    foreach ($ref as $infoKib) {

       $html .= '   <div class="gallery-grids animated slideInUp" style="text-align:center">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 gallery-grid" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                            <div class="grid effect-apollo animated fadeIn"> 
                                <a class="example-image-link" href="'.$infoKib->infografik_imgurl.'" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="'.$infoKib->infografik_title_my.'">
                                    <img class="animated fadeIn" src="'.$infoKib->infografik_imgurl.'" alt=""/>
                                    <div class="figcaption">
                                        <p>'.$infoKib->infografik_title_my.'</p>
                                    </div>  
                                </a> 
                            </div>
                            <p class="animated slideInUp" style="font-size:12px; color: #514a4a; padding-top:5px"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Kemaskini pada '.$infoKiblat->updated_dt.'</p>
                            <p class="animated slideInUp" style="font-size:12px; color: #514a4a"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> '.$infoKib->infografik_hits.' Lihat</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>';              
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
$ref = EsolatInfografik::model()->findByAttributes(
     array(
        'infografik_category'=>'Info Kiblat'
     ), 
     array(
        'order'=>'infografik_category'
     )
);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I've tried this and it still not working

Comment: What issue are you currently getting?

Comment: Using $this when not in object context
Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.findByAttributes()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');

Comment: i had this error occur

Error 500

         
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: In your code you have a variable called $infoKiblat and not $infoKib